# Google CSE autocomplete JSON api

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm using a paid version of Google CSE. I can use autocomplete with this service (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/autocomplete)

I have two questions about this.
- Can I use this service in the JSON api?
- Does a autocomplete count as a 'hit'?